Is there an intended way to incapsulate SeriesHelper in InfluxDB-python
I would like to create a table in InfluxDB and then write a pandas dataframe to it. Thus, I need to develop a function:
def write_df_to_influx(df: pd.DataFrame, client: InfluxDBClient, table_name: str, tag_names: list, field_names: list)

The official documentation states that the intended way of writing entries in bulk is to use SeriesHelper class. The documented use case seems to suggest that I need to create a class inside of a class, where I would explicitly specify the bulk_size, as well as the fields and tags. I do not really understand this design choice, but my only concern is how to use it in a generic manner to write my function.
Is it safe to create __init__ method for MySeriesHelper, that would init the parent SeriesHelper, and also use additional parameters to pass directly to the nested Meta class? I'm not an expert in python OOP, and I am mildly afraid that the SeriesHelper has some hidden rules that I need to follow.
class MySeriesHelper(SeriesHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, my_meta: dict = None, **kwargs):
       super(MySeriesHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.my_meta = my_meta

    class Meta:
       tags = self.my_meta['tags']
       # More of the Meta class omitted

If I was able to create a generic class as described above, I would have been able to write my function more or less like this
def write_df_to_influx(df: pd.DataFrame, client: InfluxDBClient, table_name: str, tag_names: list, field_names: list)
    my_meta = {'client': client, 'tags': tag_names, 'fields': field_names, 'bulk_size': len(df)}
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        MySeriesHelper(my_meta=my_meta, **dict(row))
        
    MySeriesHelper.commit()
    

Edit: Oh, so in Python nested class does not have access to the attributes of the parent class. What am I supposed to do then?

So there exists this DataFrameClient class, which already does what I want. I wonder what's the use case for SeriesHelper then...
